# How to overide web_kanban Js file to project_inherit?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I would like to customize the number of items a kanban view shows before the user has to click the 'show more' button. In addons/web_kanban/static/src/js/kanban.js there is the following snippet of code:
I want example to override js file to customized module

```
instance.web_kanban.KanbanView = instance.web.View.extend({
    template: "KanbanView",

    ...
    init: function (parent, dataset, view_id, options) {
        this._super(parent, dataset, view_id, options);
        ...
        this.limit = options.limit || 40;
        ...
    },
```